# Upload MS Word File to different Server using ftp

Tags: php, file-upload

I am hosting my website on server1 and I am trying to upload an attachment file to Server2. Here is the script, after uploading the files getting message "successfully uploaded /tmp/phpjmhXhk", but could not see any file on the Server2.

```
<?php
        $ftp_server = "ftp.xlphp.net";
        $ftp_user_name = "xl_2025****";
        $ftp_user_pass = "******";

//Upload MS Word File to different Server using ftp

if ((isset($_POST["MM_upload"])) && ($_POST["MM_upload"] == "form1")) {
// UPLOAD TO DIFFERENT SERVER // TESTING
            $RESUMENAME=$_FILES['CANDRESUME'] ['name'];
            $UploadTmp=$_FILES['CANDRESUME']['tmp_name'];
            $UploadType=$_FILES['CANDRESUME']['type'];
            $UploadExtn=substr($RESUMENAME, strpos($RESUMENAME, '.')+1); 
            $FileSize=$_FILES['CANDRESUME']['size'];
        $file = $UploadTmp;
        $remote_file=$RESUMENAME;
        echo "File".$file."</br>";
        echo "RemoteFile".$remote_file."</br>";
        $conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server);
         $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
         ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
        if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
         echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
        } else {
         echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
        }

// close the connection
            ftp_close($conn_id);

// UPLOAD TO DIFFERENT SERVER // TESTING === ENDS
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  <table width="200" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>FILE UPLOAD WITH FTP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="CANDRESUME"></label>
      <input type="file" name="CANDRESUME" id="CANDRESUME" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Upload" id="Upload" value="Submit" />
      <input name="MM_upload" type="hidden" id="MM_upload" value="form1" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried    $conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server, 21); also

Answer (score 0):

finally it worked with little change...

```
ftp_connect($ftp_server);
```

Removing SSL worked for me, but I am not sure that is the right way or not.